# Unity: Get a random value from a probability distribution

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, statistics, accord.net

I would like to get a random value from a von Mises distribution using the Accord.NET framework for statistics. It should return a float between -pi and pi, where it's most likely to return values close to the mean. The end goal is to have a player perform a random walk, where it's more likely to walk in a certain direction. Currently I am only able to generate a distribution.

```
public class RandomWalk : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start()
    {
        // Creates von Mises distribution with default mean 0 and concentration 1            
        var vonmises = new VonMisesDistribution();
    }

}
```

The von Mises is not necessary, I am looking for a way to retrieve a random value from any probability density (e.g. normal distribution).

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own method that does this.. 
We know the normal distribution function y =f(x). Since you need a value between -pi and pi.. we can approximate it as a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation as 2*pi/3. Generate a random value between 0 and 1 which acts as your y value and calculate your X based on this x = f-inverse(y). Your X will be between -pi and pi. Sorry I couldn't give you any existing class that you can use.